# biblatex-apa: undefined references

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I cannot, for the life of me,  get `biblatex`'s `apa` style to work. Other `biblatex` styles work fine, `apa`, however, does neither print a reference list, nor produce a citation at all (single output is key in boldprint). Warning "undefined references" is produced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}

\begin{filecontents}{apa-test-bib.bib}

@book{Labov1972,
    Address = {Philadelphia},
    Author = {William Labov},
    Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
    Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
    Year = {1972}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{apa-test-bib.bib}

\begin{document}

Bla \cite{Labov1972}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I run the newest version available of all packages.
Can someone help, please? Am I just overlooking the obvious?

Comment: Just checking, are you running `bibtex` or `biber` on the file?  (You've specified `backend=biber`, which means you need to use it to sort the references, not `bibtex`.)

Comment: I used biber. As I said, it works fine for the other styles. I'm guessing it must be a problem with biblatex-apa.

Comment: Your document works fine on my system (TeXLive 2011 on Mac).  Have you deleted all the associated `.aux` and `.bcf` files etc.?  If that doesn't change things can you add `\listfiles` to your document and add the console output to your question.

Comment: Having just updated my system I can now reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a bug in biblatex 1.7 and the `\RequireBiber[3]` setting it appears. This was changed in biblatex-apa style 4.5. You can change the apa.bbx file to `\RequireBiber[2]` to fix it. I have released version 4.6 of the style with this setting and it should be in TL today.

Comment: Cool, looking forward to that.

Comment: I recently upgraded MikTek 2.9's packages and now I get biblatex Error: Option 'sorting=apa' invalid. (when not including backend=biber).
If I use the example by die Anne I get the same error she had even if I edit apa.bbx to contain \RequireBiber[2] or \RequireBiber[1], as well as if I just replace it by the current v4.6 apa.bbx file.

This was with biblatex v1.7 and biber v.0.9.8

Comment: Yes, you have to use Biber with the style now because it needs a custom sorting specification not possible with bibtex.

Comment: Just a side note: You can see the version of biblatex-apa distributed by MiKTeX here: http://miktex.org/packages/biblatex-apa

Comment: Version 4.6 - that is the latest version

Comment: How to make these settings? where is this apa.bbx file located?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this - this was fixed a long time ago, just make sure you are using up to date versions.

Comment: I now get `! Package biblatex Error: Option 'date=apalong' invalid.` when using the  MikTeX 2.9 packages. Any clues?

Comment: Nevermind, updating to the latest version of biblatex solved the issue. Will leave comments in case someone else gets similarly stuck.

Answer (score 11):

I could replicate the error on my TeXLive 2011 Mac installation after updating to current packages via TeX Live Utility (`biblatex` 1.7, `biblatex-apa` 4.4, `biber` 0.9.8).

A quick fix for me was a change to the `apa.bbx` file in line 29:

```
\RequireBiber[3] % Biber is strictly required now due to custom sorting
```

to

```
\RequireBiber[1] % Biber is strictly required now due to custom sorting
```

I couldn't determine whether this is indeed a veritable cause for the "Empty bibliography" error you describe or an artefact due to some underlying problems. However the solution could reliably be repeated after a clean reinstall of all affected packages.

Comment: Nice fix. My system hadn't been updated in for a couple of days.

Comment: Great. That did the trick.