# Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX

Tags: biblatex, miktex, texmaker, biber

Will someone please help me to both configure Texmaker and use it so that I can use the `backend=biber` option with biblatex package. I am using MiKTeX 2.8 and Texmaker 3.1. **Please** do not simply tell me to read the manuals as I have spent most of the afternoon on them and the "working examples," rather than spending it on actually producing a paper.

I think what needs to be fixed is one or both of the BIBTEX command and my QUICKBUILD command in the configuration. What I have done is to put the `biber.exe` file into the `bin` directory in my LaTeX tree which is located in `C:/Latex/MyLatex`. I tried to set the BIBTEX command to `"C:/Latex/MyLatex/bin/biber.exe" %.aux` and then used the "Quick Build Wizard" to run PDFLATEX -> BIBTEX -> PDFLATEX. The minimum working example I'm attempting is posted below. It works using `bibtex` (and deleting `backend=biber`). I would really appreciate if one of you could provide me some direct guidance.

```
%%% Tex File
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{NumFactorsTest.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text is here.
\textcite{Akaike1973}
\textcite{Akaike1987}


\printbibliography

\end{document}


%%% BIB file
@InProceedings{Akaike1973,
   author = {H. Akaike},
   title = {Information theory and an extension of the maximum likelihood principle},
   editor = {B. N. Petrov and F. Csaki},
   booktitle = {2nd International Symposium on Information Theory},
   pages = {267-281},
   year = {1973},
   location = {Budapest: Akademiai Kiado} 
}

@article{Akaike1987,
   author = {Akaike},
   title = {Factor analysis and AIC},
   journal = {Psychometrika},
   volume = {52},
   number = {3},
   pages = {317-332},
   year = {1987}
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using latexmk? I use exactly the same setup as you do, and latexmk works for me.

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber

Comment: You are using outdated version of both [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) and [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/). You should consider updating at least MiKTeX, because MiKTeX versions >= 2.9 come with `biber` preinstalled.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154788

Answer (score 48):

You should update to the newest version of [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/), because it does already come with Biber included (by update I mean uninstall old version, install newest version, then run update manager). Biber will then be installed under

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe
```

Then you only need to tell Texmaker to use `biber %` instead of `bibtex %.aux` (see answer by Mark S. Everitt), that is all. Below you can see how I configured Texmaker.

[image: Click for full size]
<sub>Click for full size</sub>

Comment: Just a remark: The environment variable `%Programfiles(x86)%` does exist only on the 64-bit-versions of Windows. If the OP has a 32-bit-variant, the variable is `%Programfiles%` (as usual in Windows the case doesn’t matter).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will update Miktex and try again.

Comment: I upgraded to Miktex 2.9 and now I can indeed just use biber % for the bibtex command. Now I've been trying to invoke the APA style (using the commented usepackage command immediately above the uncommented one in the code provided), and this is not working. The Log says that all style files were found. The warnings are that the references are undefined. It suggests re-running Biber. I changed my quickbuild command to be PDFlatex -> Bibtex -> Bibtex -> PDFlatex but to no avail. Do you have any further suggestions? I'd sure appreciate it.

Comment: First, congratulations for upgrading ;-) Running pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex should be enough. Maybe there are problems with your Quickbuild command? Alternatively, could you try pressing F6, then F11, then F6 (F6 will run pdflatex, F11 will run biber) and see if that works?

Comment: That wasn't it. Again, the commands worked with \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} but not with \usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: Seems like this is bug, you can read more about it and how to work around it here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44006/biblatex-apa-undefined-references

Comment: That bug in `biblatex-apa` was only recently introduced and the fix followed shortly and is now being distributed by MiKTeX: http://miktex.org/packages/biblatex-apa After running the update manager, everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 15):

I think that your problem is likely to be the way you've configured Texmaker. I'm not using windows, but my tests predict that if you replace

> "C:/Latex/MyLatex/bin/biber.exe" %.aux

in your preferences with

> "C:/Latex/MyLatex/bin/biber.exe" %

then it should work. The reason is that Biber doesn't take an `.aux` file as its argument. It really operates on the `.bcf` file, so

> "C:/Latex/MyLatex/bin/biber.exe" %.bcf

will also work.

Answer (score 5):

just spent a day struggling with this too

I used the little browse icon to the side of the bib(la)tex field to find the biber program and it worked fine.

I also found that using LaTeX build option (i.e. not pdflatex,etc) for the first build  then a bibtex build on the same .tex document then pdfLaTeX build worked well.

my bibliography file bib.bib looks like (using science directs export citation):

```
@article{Kim1999188,
title = "Absorption of water vapour into lithium bromide-based solutions with additives using a simple stagnant pool absorber ",
journal = "International Journal of Refrigeration ",
volume = "22",
number = "3",
pages = "188 - 193",
year = "1999",
note = "",
issn = "0140-7007",
doi = "10.1016/S0140-7007(98)00061-9",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140700798000619",
author = "Jin-Soo Kim and Huen Lee and Sun Il Yu",
keywords = "Absorption",
keywords = "Water",
keywords = "Lithium bromide",
keywords = "Absorption",
keywords = "Eau",
keywords = "Bromure de lithium "
}
```

and the .tex file looks like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Kim1999188}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

producing

> Kim, Lee, and Yu 1999 ...
>
> References Kim, Jin-Soo, Huen Lee, and Sun Il Yu (1999). \Absorption
>   of water vapour into lithium bromide-based solutions with additives
>   using a simple stagnant pool absorber". In: International Journal of
>   Refrigeration 22.3, pp. 188{
>   193. issn: 0140-7007. doi: 10.1016/S0140-7007(98)00061-9. url: http: //www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140700798000619.

I need to learn how to tidy up the references but I hope this helps get you started

Answer (score 0):

My code stopped compiling, and so I used the instructions in the
@matth answer above. Things still did not work, even when I downloaded OP's example and run it. The issue was that biber correctly found the `.bib` file but did not extract any entries from the `.tex` file. This resulted in the "bold letters". From [this blog entry](https://jeetblogs.org/post/solving-the-could-not-find-all-biber-source-files-error/) I learned that it may help to clear biber's cache (disclaimer: I am not an advanced user, and I am not sure how biber uses cache and what the consequences may be).

Running the command below in Terminal solved my issues.

```
rm -rf $(biber --cache)
```