# Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows

Tags: biblatex, miktex, windows, biber

***Update***: As of summer 2015 Biber is also included in the 64-bit repositories for MikTeX. There is no need to install Biber manually any more, it can simply be installed via the Package Manager just like other packages.

The question [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex) describes how to use Biber with MiKTeX. But on the 64-bit version of MiKTeX Biber isn't installed.

How it is possible to install Biber on a 64-bit version of Windows?

Can I use this [file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.0/binaries/Windows/)?

Comment: You will be happy to know that as of summer 2015 the 64-bit version of MikTeX ships with its own version of Biber. So there is no need for a manual install any more.

Comment: Would you mind including a prominent message that manually downloading Biber for 64-bit MikTeX is not necessary any more, as Biber is now included in the repositories? Since this question is highly viewed and highly voted it causes confusion for quite some people, I would really appreciate a visible warning that the premise of the question is now outdated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Edit October 2015:** MikTeX now includes the 64-bit version of Biber.

`Biber` is only included in the 32-bit version of `MiKTeX`. Either install the 32-bit version (the 64-bit version is still experimental) or download [Biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/) and copy `biber.exe` to `$texfm$\miktex\bin`.

Comment: In addition, you have to run "Refresh FNDB" in `MiKTeX`settings so that `MiKTeX` knows about the file. And in my case the correct path was: `$texfm$\miktex\bin\x64` because on a 64bit system, `WinEdt` seems to be configured to look for binaries in that path. Though formally, it may not be correct to but the file there since it is not 64bit...

Comment: On Win7 64-bit system with MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit, put biber `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64`. In TeXstudio 2.6.6, go to Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands > Biber > [click yellow "Restore Default" arrow on right side **OR** type `biber.exe %`]. Then go to the Build tab and choose Default Bibliography > `txs:///biber`.

Comment: @Cerran: Nope. On the contrary, you should **avoid** to add manual installations into main MiKTeX installation. See also [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69487) and [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69483).

Comment: @Jörg Unfortunately your answer is despite the votes bad because of your advice for the installation into main MiKTeX path, cf. my comment to Cerran above and this answer to a missed duplicate [How can one install biber on miktex 64-bit?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154710).

Comment: @Speravir We are talking about a single executable file here, hence the drawbacks of copying it to the main MiKTeX path should be minor. But your comment now highlighted the point to anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to update this answer to indicate that 64-bit Biber has finally arrived in MikTeX? There is no need for any manual fiddling any more, one can just install the version from the MikTeX repositories.

Comment: Where do MikTex grabs packages, I'm literally been installing biber for more than an hour. **Servers suck!**

Answer (score 8):

There is no special 64-bit version for Windows - the 32-bit version should work fine.

Comment: Then I install manually Biber because Biber comes _probably_ only with the 32-bit version of MiKTeX.

Comment: (http://miktex.org/packages/miktex-biber-bin) This version is only 32-bit.

Comment: @EricDanielski MikTeX now has a version of Biber also in the 64-bit repositories.

Answer (score 6):

***Update from moeve (OP):*** "As of summer 2015 Biber is also included in the 64-bit repositories for MikTeX. There is no need to install Biber manually any more, it can simply be installed via the Package Manager just like other packages."

As Speravir mentioned in a comment to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63048/46459), manually adding files to the MiKTeX directory is not a proper solution to the problem. According to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69484/46459) of theirs, it should be avoided for security reasons.

A more secure solution is the one [offered here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154710/46459) by Bernard, reprinted here:

> Download [`miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma`](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-biber-bin.tar.lzma) from a CTAN repository (direct linked to a mirror near you) and extract the files anywhere on your computer (two steps under Windows). You get a ‘texmf’ directory containing 3 subdirectories (doc, miktex and tpm). You just have to put these 3 subdirectories under the root of your LocalTeXMF directory, and to refresh the FNDB via MiKTeX Options (‘Settings (Admin)’).
>   If you do not have a LocalTeXMF directory, create one first and declare it via MiKTeX Options, ‘Root’ tab, see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

Comment: A version of Biber has been uploaded to the MikTeX repositories that can be used with 64-bit MikTeX. There should be no need form manual installations any more. Would it be possible to change this answer to reflect that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), another way to get biber is to just install that package. It is available for the 64 bit version of cygwin.