# Reverse citation order of two library entries

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have the following problem illustrated by a simple example: If I cite the paper of an author T. Coven in my document, the outcome is 'Coven (2004b)'. If I cite the appendix to this paper, the outcome is 'Coven (2004a)'. Now the appendix pops up much less frequently than the original paper, therefore I would like to reverse the order (exchange 'a' and 'b' in the citations). Is this possible?

I am using Biblatex. Here is the bib-file of the above example (named: lib.bib):

```
@article{co:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
@article{coapp:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Appendix to Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    dashed=false,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=100,
    firstinits=true,
    sorting=nty
    ]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lib}

\begin{document}
\cite{co:2004} and \cite{coapp:2004}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you will have to adjust the sorting manually by providing some sort of `sort...` field for `biblatex`, so it knows how to sort the entries.

You use a `authoryear` style, but a `nty` sorting ("name-title-year" sorting), that seems odd. If you want to stick with it, go with the `sorttitle` field and do something like

```
@article{coapp:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Appendix to Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sorttitle = {Title A/Appendix},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    dashed=false,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=100,
    firstinits=true,
    sorting=nty,
    ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{co:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
}
@article{coapp:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Appendix to Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sorttitle = {Title A/Appendix},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{co:2004,coapp:2004}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

---

A more natural sorting choice for a Author-Year style would be `sorting=nyt` or even `sorting=nyvt` (sorting by "name-year-title" and "name-year-volume-title" respectively). In that case you could go with

```
@article{co:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sortyear = {2004-1},
}
@article{coapp:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Appendix to Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sortyear = {2004-2},
}
```

or (thanks again to lockstep)

```
@article{co:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
}
@article{coapp:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Appendix to Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sortyear = {2004/1},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    dashed=false,
    autocite=footnote,
    maxcitenames=3,
    mincitenames=1,
    maxbibnames=100,
    firstinits=true,
    sorting=nyt,
    ]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{co:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004-1},
}
@article{coapp:2004,
  author = {T. Coven},
  title = {Appendix to Title A},
  journaltitle = {The X Journal},
  date = {2004},
  sortyear = {2004-2},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{co:2004,coapp:2004}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Both methods yield

[image]

Comment: nice, thanks. Exactly what I needed. I will follow the second suggestion that you have made, using `sorting=nyvt`.

Comment: +1. However, the OP uses `backend=bibtex8`, which will result in an incorrectly sorted bibliography with `sorttitle = {Title A, Appendix}`. For the correct result, use `sorttitle = {Title A/Appendix}`.

Comment: @lockstep Nice to know. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: I just noticed the solution for `sorting=nyvt` doesn't work, maybe also because of `backend=bibtex8`?

Comment: @TomM Does it work if you have `sortyear` for both the entries, such as `sortyear={2004-1}` for `co:2004` and `sortyear={2004-2}` in `coapp:2004`? You can always switch to Biber, though; then all the solutions above work properly.

Comment: @moewe I tried to switch to Biber but it doesn't work. I am using Miktex and yesterday I upgraded all packages, but still I always get errors trying to use Biber with TexStudio, so I gave up on it. Also Bibtex seems to work fine, I cannot see any possible improvements? Edit: using `sortyear={2004-2}` works!

Comment: The error is always `Undefined control sequence \endentry` using biber

Comment: @TomM I don't know why Biber doesn't work for you right now, but section 2.4 of the `biblatex` manual provides some examples why you should rather use Biber than BibTeX.

Comment: I see. Well the error in more detail is \endentry            
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., \hobx'), type I and the correct
spelling (e.g., I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined. If I save as a new tex.file and compile it works, but pops up Could not start the command: biber.exe

Comment: @TomM With `backend=bibtex8`, use `sortyear` for both entries as suggested in moewe's last comment. Alternativly, use `sortyear={2004/x}` (the slash instead a hyphen is crucial).

Comment: @TomM If you haven't cleaned the temporary files, you will get the error messages about `\endentry` and some more on the first run of LaTeX (that's due to old auxiliary files) it is safe to ignore these errors and press on, after a biber run and a further LaTeX run, you're fine. `Could not start the command: biber.exe` seems more problematic though, check the MikTeX package manager whether biber is actually installed.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the hint. And I found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows

Who would have thought that biber is not installed on a x64 Version of Windows? :/

Comment: @TomM That's all this 32/64 bit business for you. But as noted there, you can install the 32 bit version even if you do use the 64 bit MikTeX.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `sorttitle` field. See section 2.2.3 of the `biblatex` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{co:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Title A},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
@article{coapp:2004,
author = {T. Coven},
title = {Appendix to Title A},
sorttitle = {Title A/Appendix},
journaltitle = {The X Journal},
date = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    dashed=false,
    sorting=nty
    ]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{co:2004} and \cite{coapp:2004}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]