# Migrating Texniccenter and Biber to a new computer fails

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, texniccenter

I had a running system with Miktex 2.9 and Biber as well as Texniccenter 1 on a W7 machine. Now I bought a new W7 machine and wanted to reproduce the system on this machine. I installed the same Texniccenter version and the latest Miktex 2.9.5105. I also downloaded Biber from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/latest/download) and moved it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin`.

I then exported the output profiles from my old Texniccenter Installation and imported them in the new one.

The problem now when compiling on exactly the same .tex-files (after having deleted all the stale AUX-files etc.): I don't get any errors, but a lot of warnings. Basically, all my references seem to be `undefined`. E.g.: `Latex warning: citation 'oreilly_2005' on page 92 undefined on input line 201`.

I also went into the Settings and Settings (Admin) of Miktex and "refreshed the FNDB", didn't help.

I don't understand what the problem is, as, apart from the new Miktex (and probably biber version), everything is the same as on the old machine.

Comment: biber comes with miktex no? Do you set the the `Do not run bibtex with this project` etc.? Also do you see Biber firing up some logging comments in the log file?

Comment: Do you use MiKTeX 32-bit or 64-bit? You should install TeXnicCenter 2.x. And you should never, _never,_ **never** add manual installations into your main MiKTeX installation. One day you will forget, that you added something manually, will change the MiKTeX installation, and will get errors then. Also will your manual addition not be updated automaticly. See [Purpose of local texmf trees](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69487).

Comment: @percusse: Biber is a 32bit program and is therefore only installed with 32bit MiKTeX.

Comment: See also [How can one install biber on miktex 64-bit?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154708).

Comment: Aarrgh, I overlooked this: `C:\Program Files (x86)` stands for 32-bit programs in a 64-bit Windows …

Comment: I somehow solved this by reinstalling MiKTeX in the 32-bit version and deleting all temp files. @percusse was somehow right, it also installed Biber (not in the first attempt, though). I also configured MiKTeX to automagically install packages when needed (without that, compilation always crashed with "GUI framework cannot be initialized" or something. This question can be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an installation difference of 32-bit and 64-bit MiKTeX version and it was solved by reinstallation of MiKTeX.