# Problem compiling with Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem about use `biblatex` with my document, and my MWE is like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
            style       = alphabetic,
            sorting     = nyt,
            sortcites   = true,
            autopunct   = true,
            babel       = hyphen,
            hyperref    = true,
            abbreviate  = false,
            backref     = true,
            backend     = biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\defbibheading{bibempty}{}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{BLAL}
\lipsum[1-2]
\section{BLAL}
\lipsum[1]
\section[1-3]
This is example citation book for \cite{book_key} , and further more see citation article for \cite{article_key}
Prosedure compile this dokumen :
\begin{enumerate}
\item pdflatex
\item biber
\item pdflatex x 2
\end{enumerate}
\chapter*{Daftar Pustaka}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Daftar Pustaka}
\section*{Buku}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Buku}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book]
\section*{Artikel}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Artikel}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article]
\end{document}
```

And my bib file like this :

```
@book{book_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, John},
    title = {Book title},
    year = {2012},
    volume = {3},
    series = {2},
    edition = {1},
    pages = {123--200},
    month = {January}
}

@article{article_key,
    address = {City},
    publisher = {Publisher},
    author = {Smith, James},
    title = {Article title},
    year = {2013},
    volume = {14},
    number = {6},
    pages = {1--8},
    month = {March}
}
```

I try compiling with the following procedure:

1. pdflatex
2. biblatex
3. pdflatex
4. pdflatex

But I get error messages like this:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "tesbib"
Startup Folder: D:\tes bib

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: tesbib.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file tesbib.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file tesbib.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file tesbib.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

And **I don't know How to solve it**

And I'd like my output be as follows:

[image: ioo]

Comment: You need to use biber not bibtex. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't have biber.exe and where is can i download it ?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/ (you need biberMSWIN.zip, version 1.9).

Comment: It's Perfect after I to do (1) Copy and paste biber.exe at C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64 (2) Refresh FNDB and (3) Update Formats (4) Instal LaXify at WinEdt ,

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* install `biber.exe` ins the main MiKTeX directory, but in a local TeXMF. You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154708/how-can-one-install-biber-on-miktex-64-bit).

Comment: .... And why not?

Comment: @karlkoeller: I think it's a better policy to separate personal packages installation from main MiKTeX installation. It's easier to manage updates and there's no risk personal installations being overwritten on MiKTeX updates.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that Biber is a "personal" package :-)

Comment: No, of course, but in a way it is a personal installation by not being installed by MiKTeX itself. Probably in the case of biber, there's no special risk, but don't think if you begin installing packages in MiKTeX's main directory, there's a serious risk it ends up in a mess?

Comment: On My opinion, biber.exe maybe replace biblatex for better citation, so I agree kalkoeller opinion.

Comment: biber is an executable designed to work `with` biblatex (which is not an .exe file).