# Problems with Biber (Texniccenter, Miktex,Citavi)

Tags: miktex, biber, texniccenter

I am new here as I am desperate with a latex problem.

What I use: Texniccenter, Miktex 2.9., Biber 2.5, Citavi

I have a latex model with a lot of pre settings, i will try to describe and list the relevant ones:

Main tex. includes

```
\usepackage[style=chem-angew, backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=none]{biblatex} % chem-angew
\addbibresource{LiteratureMelbourne.bib}
```

settings in texniccenter are set on using biber.exe as bibtex compiler

When I run the main tex. data the warnings occur:

```
"citation x undefined o on page y line z"
Please(re)run biber on file 
biblatex:      wissArbeit
biblatex:      and return to Latex afterwards
```

so far so good, I run biber on wissAbeit by typing in the terminal `biber wissArbeit` I receive the error message

```
the program cant be started because the data cygssp-0 is missing on the computer
```

now I am at the limits of my knowledge...can maybe someone help? I would really appreciate that!

Comment: Have installed the cygwin binary of `biber` on your own? If so, remove it and [use the MiKTeX Package Manager to install package `miktex-biber-bin` or `miktex-biber-bin-x64`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154708). Maybe you also have to update `biblatex`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i downloaded biber here:  http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/      unziped the folders and copied the biber.exe in     C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64                        is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the Problem:

As Schweinebacke said (thank you for that!) i just reinstalled the biber.exe and miktex-biber-bin-x64 files, and refreshed FNBD in the miktex settings...and somehow its working now!

can be closed , thank you