# Biber is outdated compared to biblatex

Tags: bibtex, compiling, biber

I have the following error while compiling my memoir. Here is a MWE that also gives this error:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,14pt,english,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % For Fappendixrench accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, textcomp}
\usepackage{fixcmex} %fixing lmodern and textcomp

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}


    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
    linkbordercolor = {white},
    citecolor = blue,
    }

    \addbibresource{References.bib}
   %  \AtBeginBibliography{%
   % \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   % \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   % \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   % \renewcommand*{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\mkbibbold{#1}}%
   % }


    \begin{document}
      \section{test}
    % \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    % \bibliography{References}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

---

```
Running 'biber  "Memoir-DS_Julien"'
------------
INFO - This is Biber 2.12
INFO - Logfile is 'Memoir-DS_Julien.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Memoir-DS_Julien.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.6, expected version 3.5.
This means that your biber (2.12) and biblatex (3.13) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1
Biber error: [131] Utils.pm:209> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.6, expected version 3.5.
```

`References.bib`:

```
  @article{roy1973methode,
  title={La M{\'e}thode ELECTRE II(Une application au m{\'e}dia-planning...)},
  author={Roy, Bernard and Bertier, Patrice},
  year={1973},
  publisher={Metra international}
}
```

I know this is duplicate but I couldn't find any working solutions in the following questions:

[How can one install biber on miktex 64-bit?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154708/how-can-one-install-biber-on-miktex-64-bit/154710)

[Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)

I am learning LaTeX by my own so this error is a bit harsh for me to correct. I've tried to reinstall biber and biblatex. I've tried to install a new version of biber (2.13) thanks to a local [texmf tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex) as well, but that didn't work. Biber is still under 2.12, I don't know why.

What should I do? How to check if I miss-installed biber 2.13? I'm on windows 10 64bits, I use MikTeX 2.9 and I compile thanks to the following command:

```
latexmk  -shell-escape -pdf ./Memoir-DS_Julien.tex
```

Comment: Each biber works with specific biblatex and vice-versa (with different version numbers). As you use MikTeX, the best solution consists in updating both biber and biblatex files to the latest versions, by using the MikTeX console (mpm), and ensure that you put them in the main texmf tree under C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\...

Comment: Of topic: `linkbordercolor = {white},` is useless as soon as `colorlinks` is set to `true`.

Comment: @Jhor Thank you for your comment! I want to change `Install to` path in MikTeX console (mpm) but it is stuck to `C:\Users\jke\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9` I can't find a way to change it for `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\`

Comment: There is an anomaly in the last updates of MiKTeX: `biblatex` was updated to version 3.13, but `biber` was updated in version 2.12.

Comment: @Bernard that may explain my difficulties! Do you know any fix?

Comment: In principle, when opening mom, you have to choose between user and .admin mode. You can modify the main texmf tree only in admin mode. But this suppose that you have the administrative rights on the computer. In the opposite case, perform the update in your local texmf, and instruct windows and/or latexmk to use the proper (new and local) biber.exe : by default it is searched in the 'path' which likely contains the main texmf but not yours.

Comment: Did you remember to update as both admin and user (they ose different trees for the data, so they can easily get out of sync)

Comment: No real idea, except finding somewhere  version 3.12 of biblatex. Also, you can  send a message to the author of MiKTeX on MiKTeX.org.

Comment: @Jhor I have the admin rights in my computer and I believe MiKTeX is launched with such rights. However, it never proposed  (or I don't remember that) me to choose between user and admin mode. So I can't be sure.

Comment: @daleif How should I update with both? I have no idea which mode I am. I never had to choose between both too, I think

Comment: @JKHA miktex works in mysteries ways (I don use it). Miktex admin vs user does not really have anything to do with admin right on your PC. The thing is, if you you a package that is not already installed on your system, miktex will install it for you. But it installs it in user mode under your account (AppData I think). So if you later on do a miktex admin update the packages inside the normal miktex installation is updated, but the packages that were installed as you takes precedence and may now be out of date.

Comment: I just tested: miktex install the correct biber 2.13. A small document compiles fine. So you made an installation error. Start the miktex console, normally it should ask you if you want to use admin mode. https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console.  And try to update.

Comment: @Bernard The MikTeX package manager says it's version 2.12 of Biber, but what it installs is indeed Biber 2.13. I just verified that. https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/126

Comment: Please remove all manually installed Biber and `biblatex` versions that you downloaded on your PC in the cause of trying to fix this issue. Make sure the `biblatex` and Biber packages are installed in MikTeX. Then update MikTeX as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864. If you have a multi-user installation make sure to run the updater in Admin and User mode (this is explained in the linked post with images). ...

Comment: ... For the time being ignore that the MikTeX package manager says it is installing Biber 2.12. This is a bug with the version number in the catalogue, not with the version actually installed on your system. (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/126) Just make sure you have updated your system properly and completely. Then remove all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and recompile from scratch with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: @moewe I did all you suggested and that fixed my problem, thanks! You can add an answer if you want and I'll select it

Comment: Thank you for all of you for your kind help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we start **Do not update `biblatex` or Biber manually.**

All big TeX distributions ship `biblatex` and Biber in matching versions so that usually things should work out just fine it you update your packages via the usual means of your TeX distribution. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864).

If you are using MikTeX, keep in mind that you may have to run the updater in user and admin mode (this is explained in the linked question in more detail with pictures).

In case you tried to update `biblatex` or Biber manually, remove all the files from those attempts and let your TeX distribution figure things out.

In the rare event that your TeX distribution indeed does not ship matching versions of `biblatex` and Biber alert the maintainers (TeX live via the mailing list https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live and MikTeX on GitHub https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues), issues like this are usually fixed very quickly.

After a `biblatex`/Biber update you may have to remove temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) for a smoother experience, since those files can contain version-specific definitions.

A few days ago there was a tiny glitch in the MikTeX package database. The version information of the Biber packages (for example https://miktex.org/packages/biber-windows-x64) says "2.12", but the binaries that are installed are version 2.13. This has been reported at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/126 and was resolved a few days later. But it was only a cosmetic issue, it did not impact functionality at all, since the correct version of Biber was distributed, just the package info was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an uptodate version of `biber` (v 2.13) from the links on 
https://ctan.org/pkg/biber
And install it manually.

Comment: I actually tried to do it. From this page `http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/` more precisely. I tried adding `biber.exe` in my local tree, (see posts for question links) but that didn't change my compile error

Comment: That is probably not a good idea as it might not be the official release version

Comment: @JKHA It doesn't make sense to add biber.exe to your local tree. That's an application so it should be in your path (and before the miktex/bin/ path).

Comment: Ok, I did look at the the refred posts but their are fairly obsolete ! Does the error message still says "This is Biber 2.12". In the positive case, it means that your new biber is not invoked. You should ensure that the new one (1) either is installed in the main tree or (2) that your local texmf is in system path before the main one. As I  suggested in a previous comment, and as @Ulrike Fisher added in her comment

Comment: Installing Biber manually should only be a last resort. I would even go as far as saying that the average user should *never* update Biber or `biblatex` (or indeed any package manually). Let the TeX distribution figure that out.

Comment: The round brackets in my last comment did not end up in the right place. I meant to say *I would even go as far as saying that the average user should never update Biber or `biblatex` (or indeed any package) manually.* That is I'm not advocating not to update Biber/`biblatex` at all; I'm saying not to update it *manually*.