# Bibliography in LaTeX with Biblatex and Biber as backend

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber, texniccenter

I am not able to create a bibliography with biblatex and can't figure out what the problem might be. Below are the steps I have taken which I thought would work. What am I doing wrong?

- I am using:

  - MiKTeX 2.9
  - TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 1 (64 bit)
  - JabRef 2.10
- I [downloaded](http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/latest/download) and copied manually **biber.exe** to my MiKTeX directory:

  - this step was advised [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)
  - `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\biber.exe`
- I created a new project in TeXnixCenter and a `reference.bib` file in JabRef (both in utf-8):

**LaTeX**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{ref1}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Bib-File**

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.10.
% Encoding: UTF8


@Article{ref1,
  Title                    = {Title},
  Author                   = {Phil},
  Journaltitle             = {Journal},
  Year                     = {2014},

  Owner                    = {Phil},
  Timestamp                = {2014.05.03}
}
```

- I set up the output profile in TeXnicCenter:
  [image: Output Profile]
- I compiled several times in order to create the  document but I only recived these warnings:

...

[image]

...

Comment: What happens if you try to run the commands from the command line?

Comment: @moewe: I am sorry. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is there a biber-logfile `.blg` in the directory of your example? If yes, does it show errors/warnings?

Comment: Rightclick in the windows exporer on the folder with your tex document and hold down the shift key. You will get "open command line here" in the context menu. In the command line type `pdflatex nameofyourdocument" and hit enter. Then type `biber nameofyourdocument` and hit enter. (Don't use the extension  ".tex" only the name).

Comment: @musicman: No .blg file was created.

Comment: It works for me without problem. [Here is my setup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JgaFk.png) (even though I'm using TeX Live).

Comment: @moewe: There are several warnings. After running pdflatex: 1. Citation 'ref1' on page 1 undefined on input line 7. 2. Empty bibliography on input line 8. 3. There were undefined references. After running biber: 1. data source C:\Useres\Phil\AppData\Local\Temp\...\lib\Biber\Latex\recode_data.xml not found in. And I get the same warnings everytime.

Comment: You have to run pdflatex - biber - pdflatex, and maybe again pdflatex.

Comment: @musicman: I tried but got the same warnings.

Comment: can you post your `.bib`-file, too?

Comment: @moewe: I found this [link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140814/biblatex-biber-fails-with-a-strange-error-about-missing-recode-data-xml-file). I deleted the cache folder and run biber again so the cach folder was recreated.

Comment: @musicman: I updated my question with my .bib file.

Comment: The cache folder will be recreated automatically, that is not the problem. A corrupted cache folder might be one though. But if you deleted the cache folder and the same problem persist, we can probably eliminate that as the cause.

Comment: Your `.bib` file looks perfectly fine to me. What happens if you just run `biber` on the command line (without giving the file name or anything)? What does `biber -v` output?

Comment: @Phil: I know the cache problem, I had this too, when I've started with biblatex/biber. Do you still get the error message with `recode_data.xml` or did it change?

Comment: @moewe: biber 1.8. After deleting the cache folder I recieved different warnings and errors but now it works. I have no idea why. All I did was deleting the folder, create a new minimalized .bib file and run pdflatex and biber again and again with command line. Now it also works in TeXnicCenter. Thanks all of you.

Comment: Well, the reason is explained in the link you posted above. Sometimes Biber gets interrupted when creating the cache, if the cache is corrupted Biber does not function properly. Deleting the folder and letting Biber re-create it solves the problem. The first time you run LaTeX on a file with citations, you will receive warnings, if you have not run Biber before, but those warings can safely be ignored.

Comment: I feel like wasting your time. I should probably delete this question as it has been answered by the link I posted.

Comment: You could do that, but there is no need; we can mark your question as a duplicate of the question you linked to above.

Comment: Sounds good. Maybe it helps others to detect this problem quicker.