# Sorted bibliography not displayed

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I have a tex file that was working perfectly with several bibliography parts with different sorting options. It is no longer working! Some bibliography parts are not displayed.
My OS is Windows 7 Pro on a 64 bit platform. I am using:
- TexnicCenter v2.02 stable 64 bit
- Miktex 2.9 (with biblatex updated to v2.9a)
- Biber v1.9 for biblatex v2.9

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}  

\usepackage{filecontents}  

\begin{filecontents}{refs1.bib}  
@book{bbb,  
title      = {bbb},  
publisher  = {bbb},  
author     = {BBB, Bbb},  
year       = {2012}  
}  
@book{ccc,  
title      = {ccc},  
publisher  = {ccc},  
author     = {CCC, Ccc},  
year       = {2014}  
}  
\end{filecontents}  

\begin{filecontents}{refs2.bib}  
@book{aaa,  
title      = {aaa},  
publisher  = {aaa},  
author     = {AAA, Aaa},  
year       = {2013}  
}  
\end{filecontents}  

\usepackage[  
style=authoryear,  
firstinits=true,  
backend=biber]{biblatex}  

\addbibresource{refs1.bib}  
\addbibresource{refs2.bib}  

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{ref1_cat}  
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{ref2_cat}  

\addtocategory{ref1_cat}{bbb,ccc}  
\addtocategory{ref2_cat}{aaa}  

\begin{document}  

Main text. See refs \parencite{ccc,aaa,bbb}.  

\printbibliography[title={Bibliography},sorting=nyt,heading=bibintoc]  
\nocite{*}  

\appendix  

\printbibliography[title={Only ref 1 (nyt)},category=ref1_cat,sorting=nyt,heading=bibnumbered]  
\nocite{*}  

\printbibliography[title={Only ref 1 (ydnt)},category=ref1_cat,sorting=ydnt,heading=bibnumbered]  
\nocite{*}  

\end{document}
```

The output is the following:

[image]

The bibliography with `ydnt` sorting scheme is not displayed.
Since such kind of examples was working fine before, I am suspecting an incompatibility between biber v1.9 for windows and biblatex which I has recently updated to v2.9a (I guess the previous version was v2.9).

When I compile the tex code, I have the following warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: File 'error_biber1.9_bilatex2.9a.bbl' is wrong format version - expected 2.4.
```

The format of the generated bbl file is v2.3.

Is there any solution to this problem? I wanted to get back to the previous version (prior to v2.9a) of the biblatex package under Miktex but could not find how to do that (this is probably not the solution ...). I have no other option than to use biber v1.9 released for Windows and it is expected to work with biblatex v2.9, not v2.9a!

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Biber 1.9 and `biblatex` 2.9 should match. And indeed the `bbl` format version to be expected is 2.4; but biber 1.9 should give you v. 2.4. So make sure that you really are running biber 1.9 by checking the output of `biber -v`. You could also try and update MikTeX and if that doesn't help uninstall and re-install Biber and `biblatex`. (I seem to remember some trouble about 64-bit Biber [Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63039/35864); also make sure you do not have two versions of Biber that might interfere installed.)

Comment: This was the point! I was using biber v1.8 instead of v1.9. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If you are using MikTeX it is better to install Biber via MikTeX and let it do the updating, so you can be (fairly) sure that the `biblatex` and Biber versions are in sync.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a mismatch of the `biblatex` and Biber versions, which since has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved.
The version of biber I had was downloaded from http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/ , Download. It was not biber v1.9 but v1.8. This version of biber was working fine prior to the update biblatex v2.9a.
I replaced it by the one available available at http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/1.9/binaries/Windows/ .
Everything works perfectly now!