# Remote bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

Does someone know if it is possible to load a bibliography file located in Google Drive? For instance, I would like to use

```
\bibliography{https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx_9L7GzTcK2ZE1EalZ1vFlzSjg/edit?usp=sharing}
```

is it possible to do that? I am aware that this works with Dropbox.

Comment: No, BibTeX is not able to do HTTP requests. Biber should be, but it requires loading the `biblatex` package in your document and changing some parts of it.

Comment: I still have a problem, I created the following MWE

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bx_9L7GzTcK2N2pndmpOVThBUjg&export=download}

\begin{document}
\citep{Reference0000}
\printbibliography
\end{document}

But Biber gives me errors when I compile it:

Process started

Use of uninitialized value $llabel in concatenation (.) or string at

Comment: C:\Users\HUMBER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\par-68756d626572746f736869726f6d6f746f\cache-6bef6bfac2f8155f13b160f6720d3dbe6a10b684\inc\lib/Biber.pm line 675.

Use of uninitialized value in string eq at C:\Users\HUMBER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\par-68756d626572746f736869726f6d6f746f\cache-6bef6bfac2f8155f13b160f6720d3dbe6a10b684\inc\lib/Biber/SortLists.pm line 77.

Comment: INFO - This is Biber 1.8 INFO - Logfile is 'R0V2.blg' INFO - Reading 'R0V2.bcf' WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.6, expected version 2.5 INFO - Found 8 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bx_9L7GzTcK2N2pndmpOVThBUjg&export=download' for section 0 INFO - Data source 'https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0Bx_9L7GzTcK2N2pndmpOVThBUjg&export=download' is a remote BibTeX data source - fetching ...

Comment: INFO - Decoding LaTeX character macros into UTF-8 INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'C:\Users\HUMBER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\yaLbXAkcT8\biber_remote_data_source_0skX0.bib'

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: Does someone knows what could cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using`biblatex`, but it is mandatory to use `biber` as backend. You need to use

```
\addbibresource[location=remote]{*url*}
```

The file .bib in google drive must be public, or accessible by link, and it is necessary change the *url* from: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/XXXXXXXX/edit?usp=sharing` to `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=XXXXXXXX&export=download`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0BxJDztsS-HbsZ1hTOXQ0S0w0d1U&export=download}
\begin{document}
\cite{Box1972}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did as you posted in the example. However, I was not able to make it work. When I execute bibTeX it says:


This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: 2014 09 16.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file 2014 09 16.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file 2014 09 16.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file 2014 09 16.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Comment: @Humberto You must run `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

Comment: @mvkorpel how can I do it in windows? I tried to type biber in the command prompt but it did not work.

Comment: @Humberto If "did not work" means that the command was not found, read on. Assuming that running BibTeX in the command prompt works, this probably means that Biber is not installed. I don't know much about TeX distributions on Windows, but if you are using MiKTeX (64-bit): [Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63039/23160)