# How to remotely read a bib file from Google drive?

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is a follow up question to the link below:
[Remote bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201470/remote-bibliography)

I have the same problem, I can't use a bib file from Google drive. I'm sure I'm running Biber and `biblatex`, because if I use a local location it works just fine. Yet Biber wouldn't find the remote bib file...

What I'm not so sure of is whether I'm getting the URL correctly. What I did was make the for public and the downloaded it after which I could get a URL. That was the URL I used. Is that the correct way to obtain the correct URL?

Comment: Can you show the actual code that you used?  What happens when you run the sample document in the accepted answer of the linked question?  Do you get errors? If so, what are they? That code compiles properly for me.

Comment: There seems to be a difference between the `docs.google.com...` URL in the sample document and URLs generated from Google Drive `drive.google.com...`.  I can't get the latter to open.

Answer (score 4):

In order to use a Google Drive URL with `biber` you need to change the URL that Google Drive shares and modify it in the following way:

The default sharing link (if you click on the Link Sharing icon in Drive) looks like this, where `FILE_ID` is the long number after the `=` sign:

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID
```

Alternatively, if you copy the link that normally gets emailed to someone (copied from the Share icon in Drive) the link will look like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/view?usp=sharing
```

In either case, you need to change the URL to the following:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=FILE_ID&export=download
```

This URL should now work properly with `biber`.

Comment: This is what I have:
\usepackage[style=apa,citestyle=authoryear,maxnames=2,maxbibnames=9,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource[location=remote]{https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1jZYhxUIQloSkZvNVRoYU9WRlU&export=download}

The URL that I got from drive was: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1jZYhxUIQloSkZvNVRoYU9WRlU
But still it doesn't work. The error reads:

ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: C:\Users\miranda\AppData\Local\Temp\xloic3a5f_\biber_remote_data_source_NNwWH.bib_536.utf8, line 1, syntax error: found "oboto", expected ","
Citation 'houlsby2007principles' on page 1 undefined

Comment: @Felipemir Right. Change the URL in the way I describe in the answer and it should work.

Comment: OK I got it working... with this one \addbibresource[location=remote]{https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B1jZYhxUIQloSkZvNVRoYU9WRlU&export=download}

Thanks!!

Comment: @Felipemir If Alan's answer helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it, that is our preferred way to say thank you.