# How can I use a central .bib-file for alle my LaTeX documents which is shared between Mac and Windows?

Tags: bibliographies, external-files, kpathsea, tds

I already know how to use a central .bib-file on my Mac **or** on Windows. I just use the absolute path to the file (which I can store in a Dropbox folder). On my Mac I use for example something like this:

```
\bibliography{/Users/myname/Documents/blabla/Bibliographie/biblio.bib}
```

But since the folder structure is different on Windows, I'd like to know how I can use one `.bib`-file which is shared between Windows and Mac without changing the path in the respective `.tex`-file. (The `.tex`-file is also shared via Dropbox.)

I read of the possibility to save a file in the folder of the TeX distribution, but I don't know how I can refer to that folder within my document. Can I then just use a relative path as if the file would be in the folder of the specific document? Or is there another way?

Comment: Use a relative path...

Comment: With Biber you can also use the file from dropbox directly using its URL, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201470/35864).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume you file `document.tex` is saved in Dropbox in `Documents/newdocument/document.tex` and your `bibliography.bib` is saved in Dropbox in `Documents/bibliographies/bibliography.bib` then use

```
\bibliography{../bibliographies/bibliography}
```

in `document.tex`. `../bibliographies/bibliography.bib` is called a relative path, where `../` means: *go to the parent folder*.

Now, you can mount the Dropbox directory `Documents` everywhere in your local file system. If you open `document.tex` from there, `bibliography.bib` should be found via the relative path.

For alternatively saving a file in a TEXMF examined by the TeX distribution have a look into [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137). The main difference between `.cls` (or `.sty`) and `.bib` files is, that `.cls` files are stored into subfolder `tex/latex/<myfolder>/<myfile.cls>` and `.bib` files should be stored into `bibtex/bib/<myfolder>/<myfile.bib>`. In this case you don't need a (relative or absolute) path at the `\bibliography` command but only the basename of the `.bib`-file.