# Bit information

Tags: miktex

I have MikTeX 2.9.4533 installed in my computer. Is it 64 bit software or 32 bit?
How will I find out whether an application installed is 64 bit or 32 bit supporting?
I have 64 bit machine. The editor is WinEdt 9 which is 64 bit.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx! MiKTeX is available in both 32- and 64-bit forms, so it will depend what you've installed. Moreover, it should not really make a difference in use!

Comment: Biber is not available in the 64-bit port of MiKTeX, see [Install Biber in MiKTeX on a 64-bit version of Windows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)

Comment: Also it is not likely that you will get any benefit of using 64-bit LaTeX. 32-bit works just fine even on 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which installer version did you use?  In the image

[image: Download installer]

you can see the different versions you can choose to install.

If you do not know which one is installed look with the windows explorer if MikTeX is installed in directory `x86`. Then you used the 32 bit version. If not it is the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion in the other answer will suffice if you used the default install location. But this is really just a convention: nothing's to stop a 64-bit program from being installed in `Program Files (x86)` or a 32-bit program from being installed in `Program Files`, or indeed either of them in any other location.

The way to be sure is to start a program (here `pdflatex`) on the command line and check its process using Windows Task Manager. Use `CTRL + SHIFT + ESC` to open the Task Manager, and navigate to the "Processes" tab, then scroll to the program/process name in question.

If `*32` follows the executable name, you installed a 32-bit version. If not, a 64-bit version is installed. A screenshot:

[image]