# Biber on TeXworks error: Process crashed

Tags: bibliographies, miktex, installing, biber

I am working on TeXworks with MikTeX 2.9 and I need to install Biber.
I downloaded the last version (2.6), saved the .exe file in the document file folder, then I opend TeXworks -> Edit -> Preferences -> Typesettings, in 'Processing tools' I added the voice with Name 'Biber', I browsed with Program to find the biber .exe file and I added the argument '$basename'.
Nonetheless, when I compile the document in 'Biber', it crashed immediately (Console output: 'Process crashed').
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try using a cmd and do the biber run there. What's the output?

Comment: Thank you! It gaves me a System error: can't start the program because there is no cygwin1.dll file in the computer. Any ideas? In the meantime I try to reinstall the program

Comment: The easiest way to get `biber` on a MikTeX machine is to use the version from its repositories (`miktex-biber-bin`). That works just fine (at least for me).

Comment: How do I do that? Also, am have 64 bit MikTeX, does it gives problems like said [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63039/install-biber-in-miktex-on-a-64-bit-version-of-windows)?

Comment: Just use the MiKTeX package manager (most likely the admin version of the tool) to install `biber` from the repository as TeXnician said. This prevents you from downloading the wrong binary as you have done. BTW: After installing `biber` you should update `biblatex` in "MiKTeX Updates (Admin)" *and* "MiKTeX Updates".

Comment: 2.6. is not the newest version but 2.7 and you should definitively not use the cygwin-version even if it is the one offered to you at the top of the page. If you want to install biber manually (normally not necessary as you get it with miktex) you should click through the folders until you get here https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/Windows/

Comment: You should in general not install Biber manually. Install it via your TeX distribution (on MikTeX using the 'Package Manager') and make sure to run an update afterwards to assure that the versions of `biblatex` and Biber match.

Comment: Note also that the post you link about 64bit MikTeX states quite clearly that there no longer is a difference between 64bit and 42bit MikTeX when it comes to Biber. You can install the Biber binary via the 'Package Manager' in both versions.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the clarifications, they have been very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay your problem does not seem to be a problem of `biber`, but of your general setup. If you are using MikTeX, you should definitely do the following steps:

1. Update your distribution (use the MikTeX Update tool as admin).

   [image: updater]
2. Open your package manager and install (the most recent) `miktex-biber-bin` (just click the "Install" field in the context menu or the plus button).

   [image: miktex-biber-bin]
3. Set up your editor to use that binary (it is in the `$PATH` by default, so just add `biber.exe` and `$basename`).

   [image: the last step]

Comment: Did it, thank you very much! Now when I compile in Biber it gives me the error: 'Warning: Found biblatex control file version 3.0, expected version 2.9', but I will solve it on monday... Thanks again

Comment: @Eggman Try to remove `.aux`-files etc. Probably that's just an ignorable warning.

Comment: @Eggman The version warning should not be ignored, it can lead to serious problems, that's why it has been 'upgraded' to a critical error in newer versions of Biber. The problem can occur after you have updated `biblatex` or Biber, but then it should go away after deleting the temporary files (`.bcf`, `.bbl`, `.aux`). If it does not go away, you need to check your versions of `biblatex` and Biber and update to compatible versions. If you have installed both via MikTeX's 'Package Manager', that is as easy as running the Update tool (in User and Admin mode).

Comment: Solved, thank you again. Just had to update all the packages, it has been some time since I've used LateX...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar mystery crash (exit code 2), it solved by emptying the cache:

```
rm -rf `biber --cache`
```