# BibLateX - Missing \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber

I wanted to use BibLateX with IEEE style, because of `urldate`. The problem is, I'm getting error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

I'm using `pdftex` and `bibtex` for compilation.

I'm completely new to `biblatex`, so I wrote this code according to the answers in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots).

#### Edit:

I'm using TexMaker - now with `biber` option for compilation according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex).

---

#### My code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=ieee
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{paralel_distribution.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
aaaa

aaaaaaaaaaa \cite{blackford1997scalapack}

aaaaaaaaaaa \cite{balay2014petsc}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

#### My .bib file

```
@Article{balay2014petsc,
  Title                    = {PETSc Users Manual Revision 3.5},
  Author                   = {Balay, S and Abhyankar, S and Adams, M and Brown, J and Brune, P and Buschelman, K and Eijkhout, V and Gropp, W and Kaushik, D and Knepley, M and others},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Urldate                  = {13.05.2015},

  Url                      = {http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manual.pdf}
}

@Techreport{petsc-user-ref,
  Title                    = {{PETS}c Users Manual},
  Author                   = {Satish Balay and Shrirang Abhyankar and Mark~F. Adams and Jed Brown and Peter Brune and Kris Buschelman and Victor Eijkhout and William~D. Gropp
 and Dinesh Kaushik and Matthew~G. Knepley
 and Lois Curfman McInnes and Karl Rupp and Barry~F. Smith
 and Hong Zhang},
  Institution              = {Argonne National Laboratory},
  Year                     = {2014},
  Number                   = {ANL-95/11 - Revision 3.5},
  Url                      = {http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc},
  Urldate                  = {12.05.2015}
}

@Book{blackford1997scalapack,
  Title                    = {ScaLAPACK users' guide},
  Author                   = {Blackford, L Susan and Choi, Jaeyoung and Cleary, Andy and D'Azevedo, Eduardo and Demmel, James and Dhillon, Inderjit and Dongarra, Jack and Hammarling, Sven and Henry, Greg and Petitet, Antoine and others},
  Publisher                = {siam},
  Year                     = {1997},
  Urldate                  = {13.05.2015},
  Volume                   = {4},

  Url                      = {http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/slug/}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is inside your `.bib` file? Normally, this should work

Comment: You use the `backend=biber` option, but compile with `bibtex`…

Comment: @Bernard: Making an answer?

Comment: @ Bernard Now I'm, but it's still the same :-(

Comment: Could you add a minimal bibliography, so we can test?

Comment: @Bernard Ok, I did it

Comment: @MartinBeseda: I just tried your example with the posted `.bib` file -- it runs without problems. Do you have the latest `biber` version (v. 1.9)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it compiles fine for me. Your problem looks like your  real preamble contains something that shouldn't be there. The cause may be hard to detect. Could  you post post a minimal (non) working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I have :-)

Comment: @Bernard I'm afraid, that I'm not sure, what do you mean by "minimal (non) working example" - do you mean some other code?

Comment: I suppose the code that is posted  compiles for you as it compiles for me. So your problem comes from something else and it may be hard to detect what is the problem. I suspect it comes from mistyping some part of the preamble that results in the preamble containing something that should be there. A simple dot inadvertently typed before `\begin{document}` leads to such an error. So the best you have to do is commenting package loading in the preamble,and uncommenting gradually until the problem happens again. Then you should be able to llocalise the problem.

Comment: @Bernard I tried it, it appears the mistake is caused by the `usepackage` command.

Comment: You should show more of the error message - latex tells you the line and the offending input.

Comment: Any news here? The MWE works fine here.

Comment: @moewe Unfortunately, I had to reinstall my whole system and it works fine now, so I can only guess there was some incorrectly installed package.