# Problems with biblatex and TexMaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texmaker

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[multidot]{grffile}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage[24hr]{datetime} 
\usepackage{titlesec,titletoc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 

\graphicspath{{graphs_folder/}}

\usepackage[
     backend=biber, 
     natbib=true,
     style=numeric,
     sorting=none
 ]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib}

 \begin{document}
 Hello.I want to cite \cite{braitenberg2013anatomy} and 
 \cite{hebb2005organization}

 \backmatter
 \cleardoublepage

 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, I'm using TexMaker 4.1 and I did what suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex)

However:

when I try to run the compiler with PDFLaTeX option, I obtain

```
line 50: Empty bibliography
line 1: There were undefined references
line 1: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards
```

I think is important to tell you that when I run quick build it should go through the whole process and showing me the pdf. Instead, it ends with

```
Error:could not start the command
```

and doesn't show anything. The same message appears if I use the BibTeX option of the compiler.

If I open the pdf manually, I can't find the bibliography and the citations are like

> [**braitenberg2013anatomy**] and [**hebb2005organization**]

while what I need is

> [1] and [2]

(note that I need them to be sorted as they appear).

What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and compare your settings. Can you call Biber from the command line? Can you try and compile everything from the command line? (`pdflatex test`, `biber test`, `pdflatex test`, `pdflatex test` assuming your `.tex` file is called `test.tex`) See also [Troubleshooting for biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/35864). Is there a `.blg` file? Can you post its contents here?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add the two bib entrys for `braitenberg2013anatomy` and 
 `hebb2005organization` to your question ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is given by the comment of @moewe: running

```
biber test
```

revealed biber was not installed. Everything is fine when you install it.

Comment: If you're the OP you can merge your account with the one you've asked the question with in the help section.