# Adding bibliography to file in XeLatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to add a references section to my report. However I have not been able to. I used \addbibresource, \bibliography, but no result. I have seen a lot of questions about this but nothing solved my problem, so maybe it is a package issue. I have a references file called refs.bib

What I have right now is this -

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
text text text
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

I have tried -

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\begin{document}
text text text
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This does not generate a reference page. I have tried many different things though, and I always get an error. I am working in TexMaker and am using XeLatex to compile.

I am thinking this might be a very specific problem, only applicable to my system. I will delete this if there is nothing that I have missed.

Here is the part of the log for the XeLaTex run which I thought is relevant:-

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1023 \bibliography
                    {refs.bib}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

[70

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 1024.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 1024.
 (./thesis.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 1024.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 1024.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `thesis.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 3ADE6CBD12915D7B9305AC529A3E8178.
Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'thesis.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `thesis.run.xml'.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 1024.
 )
```

The `only in preamble` error is weird because I have no packages inside the document

The log for the second piece of code is:-

```
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 1022.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 1023.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 1023.
(./thesis.aux
*************************************************
* pdfbase warning: "rerun"
* 
* Rerun to get internal references right!
*************************************************
)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 1023.
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 1023.

Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `thesis.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 3ADE6CBD12915D7B9305AC529A3E8178.


LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                thesis
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'thesis.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `thesis.run.xml'.

Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 1023.
 )
```

The BibTex log:-

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: thesis.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file thesis.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file thesis.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file thesis.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

Comment: Did you have reference entries?

Comment: Yes I do actually

Comment: The syntax to obtain a bibliography with biblatex is: `\addbibresource{refs.bib}` in the preamble, and `\printbibliography` after `\begin{document}`, at the place you want it.

Comment: Tried that too. Did not work. I will add this to my question though

Comment: Did you run the normal cycle: `pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex (twice)`?

Comment: yes I did, twice, thrice. A lot. I am using XeLatex though

Comment: I am thinking this might be a very specific problem, only applicable to my system. I will delete this if there is nothing that I have missed.

Comment: Can you show us the log file for the XeTeX and biber runs, please? (uploading to https://pastebin.com or something similar is fine).

Comment: I am pasting the log up in my question

Comment: The log you showed is from the first code (with `\bibliography`). Please show that of the second code, with `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography`.

Comment: added the logs which were relevant

Comment: @Yuki.kuroshita Aha! So the problem is that you are running BibTeX, not Biber. When you are using the `biblatex` package you need to use Biber instead (there is a compatibility mode, but let's not get into that). For TeXMaker there is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44095/134574) which shows how to configure Biber.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864 for background info.

Comment: Yes, finally, this worked. Spent the whole day trying to fix this. Please write up a proper answer

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Do you want to write up an answer, or do we close this as duplicate of one of the standard questions I linked above?

Comment: @moewe I think a duplicate might be better... I don't know which one, though. Your pick.