# How do I reference a URL from a BibTex file?

Tags: bibtex, citing, apa-style, url

I am looking for a way to reference literature including url. For instance my BibTex keys look like this:

```
@misc{UnitedNationsGeneralAssembly.2015,
 author = {{United Nations General Assembly}},
 year = {2015},
 title = {Sustainable Development Goals},
 url = {\url{https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}}
}
```

The citing in the text should be: (United Nations General Assembly, 2015) and in the references:

> United Nations General Assembly, 2015. Sustainable Development Goals. https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/

Right now I'm using `\documentclass{report}` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, but the url doesn't show up. What can I do about that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you consider using `biblatex`? It has an `apa` style and is easier to customise, as it uses a LaTeX syntax. Furthermore, it defines the `@online` entry type.

Comment: Just in case you're not familiar with `biblatex`, maybe [this answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25702/172164) might help you, it nicley explains the advantages `biblatex` can have (as well as advantages of `biber` over `bibtex`).

Answer (score 2):

The `apalike` bibliography style is very old. In fact, it is *so very old* that it predates the notion that URL strings might ever show up in a bibliographic entry. As a result, the `apalike` bib style simply ignores the `url` field.

What to do? Simply change

```
 url = {\url{https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}}
```

to

```
 note = {\url{https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}}
```

Of course, do be sure to load the `url` or, better still, the `xurl` package. (By the way, if `url` *were* a recognized field, then it would be a *syntax error* to encase the URL string in a `\url` directive. The syntactically correct way to write the field would be `url = {https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}`.)

Owing to its advanced age, the `apalike` bib style does not implement the current APA guidelines and requirements regarding the formatting of bibliographic entries. If the bibliography of your document needs to conform to modern APA guidelines, and if you want to stick with a BibTeX-based approach, do consider employing the `apacite` bibliography style and the `apacite` package.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{UnitedNationsGeneralAssembly.2015,
 author = {{United Nations General Assembly}},
 year   = {2015},
 title  = {Sustainable Development Goals},
 note   = {\url{https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[round]{natbib} % for \citep macro
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citep{UnitedNationsGeneralAssembly.2015}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

**Addendum**: As @moewe has pointed out in a comment, the `apacite` bib style and eponymous LaTeX package implement the guidelines of the *6th edition* of the APA manual. Importantly, the 6th edition has been superseded by the 7th edition within the past year or so. If you need to be truly current in your adherence to APA guidelines, you'll need to switch from `apacite` to `biblatex`. (Put differently, the `apacite` package hasn't been updated yet to reflect the changes between the 6th and 7th editions.)

To make the MWE given above work with biblatex and biber, you need to load the `biblatex` package, with the option `style=apa` (and with the option `natbib` in case you wish to use `\citet` and `\citep` to create citation call-outs) and employ `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography` statements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{UnitedNationsGeneralAssembly.2015,
 author = {{United Nations General Assembly}},
 year   = {2015},
 title  = {Sustainable Development Goals},
 url    = {https://sustainabledevelopment.un.org/}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks in URL strings at arbitrary locations
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
\citep{UnitedNationsGeneralAssembly.2015}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `apacite` implements APA style from the 6th edition of the manual and the current edition of the manual is the 7th edition. There are some changes in APA style citations and bibliography requirements that mean that `apacite` no longer conforms to *current* APA guidelines. `biblatex-apa` implements 7th-ed. APA style as far as possible with `biblatex`, `biblatex-apa6` provides the legacy 6th-ed. style.

Comment: @moewe - Many thanks for this. I've updated my answer to mention the issues you raise regarding what's the "current" APA style, and I've provided an "alternative" MWE which shows how to use the `biblatex` approach.

Comment: Is there a protocol how to switch from Bibtex to Biblatex? Is that compatible with TexMaker?

Comment: @allismind - Not sure there's anythink akin to a "protocol" for switching to biblatex/biber. Please see the postings [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/5001), [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/5001), and [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/5001). I don't use texmaker myself. However, the posting [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44040/5001) may be of use to you.