# Is there a way to apply Apa 7th references and citation style in latex?

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apacite

I was doing a research using apacite:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

The outcomes were good, but the APA manual is now at the 7th edition, and I need to know how can I do my references and citations with the APA 7th edition guidelines.

Comment: I don't think `apacite` has been updated to reflect the APA 7th edition, but `biblatex-apa` has been.

Comment: See the addendum to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525709/5001) for information on how to switch from the bibtex/apacite approach to a biblatex-based approach that incorporates the formatting requirements of the 7th edition of the APA manual.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The version of [`apacite`](https://ctan.org/pkg/apacite) currently available on CTAN (v6.03 `2013/07/21`) implements the requirements of the 6th edition of the APA manual. I am not aware of any BibTeX implementation of 7th-ed. APA style. You can of course try and contact the author of `apacite` about that and ask for 7th-ed. APA style as a feature request.

For the time being [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) is the only implementation of 7th-ed. APA citation and bibliography style that I know of. Note that you need at least version 9.0 (released 2019-11-23) of `biblatex-apa`.

Since `biblatex-apa` is `biblatex`-based, you will have to apply some changes to your document, see [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864). In particular a document using `biblatex-apa` must be compiled with Biber instead of BibTeX (some background is at [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) and [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)), so you may have to reconfigure your editor: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations and bibliography in APA style (7th ed.)]

---

`biblatex-apa` users who want to go back to 6th-ed. APA style will be interested in [`biblatex-apa6`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa6). The only change necessary is to go from `style=apa,` to `style=apa6,`.