# APA 7th edition in Latex by using the natbib and apacite

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6, apacite, apa7

I am going to do the following changes in Latex. As you know,APA format requires the & be used in parenthetical citations, when both name and year are inside the parentheses, such as (Shi & Tsai, 2002). When they are use in the discussion, spell out “and” such as “....Shi and Tsai (2002) argued that,...”
Likewise, in the references the & should be used between two authors, and between the last 2 authors in a larger group, such as:
Staicu, A., Crainiceanu, C., & Carroll, R. (2010).

For making these changes, I have done the following commands:

```
% % References
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1.7cm}{20pt} 
\setlength{\bibhang}{0.5 in}       
\singlespacing
\bibliography{mybib}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
```

But the outputs are not what I expected. Here are the outputs:
Burnham & AnderSon (2002) and Shi & Tsai (2002)... the −2× log-likelihood (Burnham & AnderSon, 2002; Shi & Tsai, 2002)...
Greven, S., Crainiceanu, C., Caffo, B., & Reich, D. (2010). Longitudinal functional principal component analysis. Electronic Journal of Statistics, 1022-1054.

Comment: please make a small but complete test file, also you have tagged this biblatex but it looks like you are using bibtex not biblatex

Comment: To use the `apacite` bibliography style, you need to load the `apacite` package too, and if you plan to use the `natbib` citation commands, you need to load it with the `natbibapa` option. I'm not sure that `apacite` implements APA 7, however, so you may want to switch to `biblatex-apa` which does.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527497/35864. In fact going by the title, your question is a duplicate of that question (it isn't made explicit in the question body that you want 7th ed. APA style).

Comment: The takeaway from the answer to the linked question is that `apacite` currently can only give you 6th-ed. APA style. (And as Alan commented above, you should load `\usepackage{apacite}` to properly use `apacite`.) If you need 7th-ed. APA style, the only LaTeX-based solution at the moment is a current version of `biblatex-apa` (which will likely require small changes to your workflow).

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a small code you should be able to compile. It is using `biblatex` and `biber`. I will compile several times if your system is configures to do so, or do it manually. See how the different ways of citing works with multiple authors.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage[%
backend=biber,
natbib=true,
style=apa,
]{biblatex} 

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname35.bib}    
@book{companion,
author       = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
title        = {The \LaTeX\ {C}ompanion},
date         = 1994,
edition      = 1,
publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
location     = {Reading, Mass.},
pagetotal    = 528,
}

@article{aksin,
author       = {Aks{\i}n, {\"O}zge and T{\"u}rkmen, Hayati and Artok, Levent
    and {\c{C}}etinkaya, Bekir and Ni, Chaoying and
    B{\"u}y{\"u}kg{\"u}ng{\"o}r, Orhan and {\"O}zkal, Erhan},
title        = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics of
    saturated {Pd-N}-heterocyclic carbenes in {Mizoroki-Heck}
    reactions},
journaltitle = {{S}eminars in {N}uclear {M}edicine},
date         = 2006,
volume       = 691,
number       = 13,
pages        = {3027-3036},
indextitle   = {Effect of immobilization on catalytic characteristics},
}

@article{bertram,
author       = {Bertram, Aaron and Wentworth, Richard},
title        = {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces},
journaltitle = {Revue d'Histoire Eccl{\'e}siastique},
date         = 1996,
volume       = 9,
number       = 2,
pages        = {529-571},
langid       = {english},
langidopts   = {variant=american},
shorttitle   = {Gromov invariants},
 }

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname35.bib}

\begin{document}    
    
\section*{Introduction}     

Two topics that I wish were taught more often are equivalence testing \citep{aksin} and ROC curves \citep{bertram}. Such methods are well supported by software \citep{aksin, companion}. That said, I confess that the cited software products have nothing to do with the topics that are mentioned.

\citet{bertram} presents some methodology on how to perform tests of equivalence,and also the one--sided versions of these, which are known as non-inferiority or non--superiority tests. On the other hand, if you want to know about receiver operating characteristic (ROC) curves, a good source of information is \citet{companion}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: xapa]

**Recommended!** https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/527526/161015