# Use of APA7 in Latex with apacite

Tags: bibtex, citing, apacite, doi, apa7

i´m using Latex with bibtex and apacite. Until some weeks ago, my university set apa6 as the current citation style, which i could perfectly put to practice, however now we have to use apa7. Since i haven´t found a solution for apa7 with apacite and bibtex, i´d like to ask you a few questions. If there already happens to exist a working solution i´m sorry for bothering you.

The first problem concerns the DOIs: previously the entry in the reference list had to look like this:
doi: xxx. By using `hyperref` the number was blue and could also be clicked.

Now the new format should look like this: https://doi.org/xxx

Does anyone of you know a solution, how to get this entry? I generated this doi by simply adding a doi entry in my `.bib` file.

Another, but smaller, problem are citations with three or more authors. According to APA6 `apacite`listed all authors when first citing the article/book etc. and for all following citations in text it only listed the first name and et al.

Now every citation of a work with 3 or more authors should list only the first name plus the "et al.", even when first citing it.
I think it´s possible to address this problem by simply using `\shortcite{}` but maybe there is an even better solution.

Here i give you a MWE:

```
\documentclass[parsikip=full,oneside, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2.8cm, right=2.8cm,top=2.1cm, bottom=19mm,includehead=false,footskip=10mm, bindingoffset=0mm ]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % Schaltet auf erweiterten Zeichensatz um
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Setzt die Zeichenkodierung
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Deutsche Sprachumgebung
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} % Paket für Anführungszeichen
\usepackage{microtype}      % u.a. optischer Randausgleich
\usepackage{color}          % Farbiger Text 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,draft = false,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}

\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}}
\addtokomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}  % Schaltet in Überschriften auf Roman-Schriften um
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont\textsc}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\clearscrheadfoot
\setheadsepline{0.4pt}
\ohead{\today} \ihead{Lukas Höhnle}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\newcommand{\anf}[1]{\glqq{}#1{}\grqq{}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\BCBL}{,}%
    \renewcommand{\BCBT}{,}%
    }

\newcommand{\zittext}[2]{\cite[S. #2]{#1}}
\newcommand{\hervor}[2]{\cite[S. #2, Hervorheb. i.O.]{#1}}

\newcommand*{\doi}[1]{\href{https://doi.org/#1}{#1}}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{APACrefDOI}{%
    \global\let\old@doi\doi
    \if@doi
    \doiprefix
    \else
    \global\let\doi\@gobble
    \fi
    \ignorespaces
}{\global\let\doi\old@doi }
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
        \Bem{#1}%             journal
        \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
        \else
        \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
        \fi
        \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
        \else
        \unskip({#3})%      issue number
        \fi
        \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
        \else
        \unskip, {#4}%      pages
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\BRetrieved}[1]{Abgerufen am {#1} von\ }%

 
%%%%%%% Bibliography
\newgeometry{left=31mm, right=31mm, top=23mm, bottom=22mm}

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{lit_memes} 

\newpage
\end{document}
```

I´d be really happy if someone knew a solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can't you use biblatex-apa? It supports apa7.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, thanks for your quick reply. 
I´m not exactly sure, but i think a switch to biblatex-apa would mess up my preamble etc. with all these individual specifications i added in the last months. However, if there is no better solution then i might have to put in some effort and switch to biblatex.

Comment: I agree with @UlrikeFischer that you should switch to `biblatex-apa`. Trying to adapt `apacite` from APA6 to APA7 is really going to cause you more problems than it's worth. And if you need conforming APA7, most of the modifications you've had to do presumably won't be needed.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/527497/35864. Basically, `apacite` can only give you 6th-edition APA style and it is going to be very painful to modify the package to give you proper 7th-edition APA style. You can probably patch some bits and pieces to get closer to 7th-edition APA, but I doubt you are going to get there without putting in a lot of work. Currently your only chance of getting 7th-edition APA style with LaTeX is an up-to-date version of `biblatex-apa`.