# BibTex Error no \bibdata command

Tags: bibtex, errors

I am looking for a solution and have read a lot on the Internet, which has not helped me further.

Here is my Latex

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}

%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\usepackage{url}

%Mathepackages
\geometry{left=4cm,right=3.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}%mathepacket
\usepackage{amsmath}%ebenfalls mathepacket
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
%\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}

\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
text
\newpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

My Literatur.bib

```
@Online{SchengenVisa,
  author = {SchengenVisaInfo},
  note   = {Aufgerufen am 08.09.2022},
  title  = {Informationen über das Schengen-Visum},
  url    = {https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/de/},
}
```

If translate with pdfLatex and then with bibTex and get the following error message.

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: Masterbericht.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Masterbericht.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Masterbericht.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Masterbericht.aux (There were 3 error messages)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You can also put both code snippets into one, see [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407). In your example you don't use any `\cite` command. And more important you use `biblatex` with option `backend=biber`. Therefore you have to use `biber` instead of `BibTeX` to compile it correctly.

Comment: How I can use biber? I use texmaker and only know how to compile with biblatex

Comment: see e.g. [Biblatex + Biber + Texmaker + MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44040/123129)

Answer (score 0):

```latex
% test.tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\geometry{left=4cm,right=3.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
text
\cite{SchengenVisa}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```shell
pdflatex test
biber test
pdflatex test
```

[image]