# APA bibliography with beamer and biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies, apa-style

I am having trouble (i.e., a complete failure) getting `beamer` to use `biblatex` and with the `apa` bibliography style. Any examples of templates that do this would be appreciated.

I have found this very helpful link:

https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/16

and with the code the author provides I can get `biblatex` into `beamer`, just not in APA format.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing this question is related to: [biblatex-apa: undefined references](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44006/biblatex-apa-undefined-references)

The following MWE works fine for me.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-UoN}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{knuth,
  author = "Donald E. Knuth",
  title = "The {\TeX}book",
  publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
  year = "1986"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \cite{knuth}
    \printbibliography
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```