# \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} does not work, backend=bibtex works

Tags: biber, texniccenter

When using the `backend=biber` option, I get a warning:

> package Biblatex warning: Please (re)run  Biber on the file:
>   (biblatex) myproject

**Result:** References are not recognized.

1. Yes. A similar question does exist - but no solution is provided: [Problem getting biber/biblatex/XeLaTeX/TeXworks working together](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46649/problem-getting-biber-biblatex-xelatex-texworks-working-together).
2. [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) - as a MWE.

`backend=bibtex` works like charm.

**Question:**
What are the detailed steps to get `backend=biber` working? (When people say run that command or another there is a need of context.)

So my editor is [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/).

And I have no clue how to run Biber on my file under TeXnicCenter... or any other environment.

**Consider me as a simple mortal that really would like to get this solved, save forever and never come back again.**

In TexnicCenter I don't have to do anything fancy with the MWE using `backend=bibtex` except creating a `.bib` file. Then I press `Build current file` - and get valid pdf with my references, which is a way it should be - simple and concise. If there is a tendency to recommand `biber` for utf-8 support, then we should get fast deployment so this will be adopted faster.

The problem inherently is the same as this one: [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber/34136).

Comment: What do exactly mean with "context" in the 'Question' part? Does your last sentence state, that your question is a dublicate or a special case of the mentioned post?

Comment: It indicates that: 1. I found no solution with step by step guidance on how to make it work - in general(and i feel it has nothing to do with the .tex code/declarations - all the MWEs using biber don't work for me. 2. And if the solution is known then I would like to know which steps I have to go through in order to make it work within TexnicCenter. Thanks for editing.

Comment: See also [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would create a new build profile, say `LaTeX > PDF (Biber)`, which is a copy of `LaTeX > PDF` (the one set up by default in TeXnicCenter):

[image]

Now add `biber` as the BibTeX compiler:

[image]

In the above "Command line arguments to pass to BibTeX", `%tm` refers to the file "Title (without extension)". You can also add other arguments to want to pass to `biber` here (like the file encoding, for example). For all options, see the [`biber` documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/biber/biber.pdf).

Now you can compile (no output) your document once under the `LaTeX > PDF (Biber)` profile and a second time under the `LaTeX > PDF` profile. In sequence, this performs a `pdflatex` > `biber` > `pdflatex` compilation. If you wish to do this in one click, you can add the following to the `LaTeX > PDF (Biber)` profile's Postprocessor tab:

[image]

The `pdflatex` process arguments are copied from the main profile page.

Running the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{mybibkey,
    author = {A. Author},
    title = {Some amazing work of art},
    journal = {A fur realz journal},
    volume = {17},
    number = {3},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {1--99}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
See~\cite{mybibkey}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

under `LaTeX > PDF (Biber)` with the added Postprocessor `pdflatex` component yields the one-click output

[image]

I would suggest keeping separate output profiles, since you only need to compile with `biber` once you have a change of bibliographic items, so you don't need to do it with *every* compile.