# Texniccenter: Biber wont find references

Tags: biblatex, biber, texniccenter

After neglecting Windows and Texniccenter for a time, I am now trying to setup my windows machine to also work with my biber files. I was following [this very extensive answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144190/39314).

My working file is exactly that working example, called LaTeX1.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}% http://ctan.org/pkg/filecontents
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}% http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex

\begin{filecontents*}{references.bib}
@article{mybibkey,
    author = {A. Author},
    title = {Some amazing work of art},
    journal = {A fur realz journal},
    volume = {17},
    number = {3},
    year = {2013},
    pages = {1--99}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
See~\cite{mybibkey}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

However, it fails to compile. Here's what I believe to be the relevant excerpt of the log file:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.
 (C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))

LaTeX Warning: Overwriting file `./references.bib'.


Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.
(C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx\english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count206
\@quotereset=\count207

("C:\Users\sdaro\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Diverse\laborMacro\LaTeX1.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
Package biblatex Info: No input encoding detected.
(biblatex)             Assuming 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'ascii'.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'LaTeX1.bbl' not found.

No file LaTeX1.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 19.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 19.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'mybibkey' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 22.

[1

{C:/Users/sdaro/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
("C:\Users\sdaro\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Diverse\laborMacro\LaTeX1.aux")

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                LaTeX1
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Here's the content of the LateX1.blg:

```
[0] Config.pm:361> INFO - This is Biber 1.5
[0] Config.pm:364> INFO - Logfile is 'C:\Users\sdaro\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Diverse\laborMacro\LaTeX1.blg'
[67] biber-MSWIN:190> INFO - === %a %b %e, %Y, %H:%M:%S
[67] Biber.pm:327> INFO - Reading 'C:\Users\sdaro\Google Drive\Cloud\PhD\Diverse\laborMacro\LaTeX1.bcf'
[136] Utils.pm:167> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.7, expected version 2.3
[137] Biber.pm:619> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[156] Biber.pm:2976> INFO - Processing section 0
[174] Biber.pm:3086> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0
[177] bibtex.pm:764> INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
```

I can assure you that in my Texniccenter profile, I have the path to the bibtex executable set as `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\biber.exe` and the command line argument `"%bm"`

Comment: Show the content of the .blg-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added that information

Comment: Your biber is way too old.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm pretty sure that TexnicCenter just auto-intalled that version today.

Comment: biber is not installed by texnicenter, texniccenter can only trigger the installation of biblatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried updating Biber through Miktex, but it seems I'm not having sufficient admin rights (to update files in the application folder). Are you positive this is likely the cause of the error? My IT staff is in vacation right now and I would like to only disturb them if it likely solves this issue.

Comment: You can download the miktex-package from Ctan, extract biber.exe and put in some folder where you have writing rights and adapt the texniccenter path.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Indeed, an old biber version was the cause. If you post this as an answer, Im happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a warning in the blg

```
136] Utils.pm:167> WARN - Warning: Found biblatex control file version 2.7, expected version 2.3
```

This warning shows that there is a mismatch between the biber version and the biblatex version. In your case biber is too old.