# Citation style mla

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to change my current bibsytle to mla but it won't work:

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliography{test-bib.bib}
\bibliographystyle{dinat}

This my text \citep{Saussure1995} text

\end{document}
```

I tried the following by using TeXnixCenter but it won't work:

```
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test-bib.bib} 
\begin{document}
This is a citation. \autocite{Saussure1995}. Another citation \autocite{Kavanaugh1976}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: When you switch from `natbib` to `biblatex` you need to make sure of two things: first, remove all your auxiliary files, and second you need use `biber` to process the bibliography, and not `bibtex`.  TeXnixCenter doesn't look at your source file to decide which tool to use, so having `backend=biber` doesn't tell the editor to use it. So you need to tell TeXnixCenter to user `biber` instead of `bibtex` for this document.  See [\usepackage\[backend=biber\]{biblatex} does not work, backend=bibtex works](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/143059) for details on how to do this.

Comment: Another good reference is [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), a bit of background is found in [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864).

Comment: Please note that the `biblatex-mla` package has not been updated since 2013; `biblatex` has progressed a bit since then, so expect some rough edges. It also lacks some commands one normally expects `biblatex` styles to implement (most notably `\textcite`, it also has trouble with `\footcite` and certain entry types; though I gather that both of these were more or less by design). (I also doubt that MLA is a drop-in replacement of `dinat.bst`, maybe you could choose another style, especially if you expect to have to do some modifications.)